# Compc "error: could not find source for resource bundle" in Flex 3 when upgrading from 2.0.1

Tags: apache-flex, resources, flex3, bundle, compc

I have moved our project from SDK 2.0.1 to 3.5 because I'm using TLF. This has compiled OK in flex builder 3 IDE but I am now using command line compilation for our build system and getting errors for all the standard Flex resource bundles: Sharedresources, collections, containers, controls etc. I can see this is because of the improvements in Flex 3 and the SDK local folder doesn't have these as .properties files but now has a framework_rb.swc.

Can anyone tell me how to get the resource bundles to compile using 3.5 SDK?

The application isn't doing anything clever with resource bundles or using the resourcebundle metatag.

Thanks,

Nigel

Answer (score 0):

I guess it means framework resource bundles can't be found on the build system machine. You should create them with the copylocale command.

> When adding other locales, you must
>   also include the framework resources
>   for that locale. The en_US locale is
>   already provided. For all other
>   locales, you must create the framework
>   resources. To create a locale’s
>   framework resources, use the
>   copylocale utility in the /sdk/bin
>   directory. For Flash Builder, the
>   copylocale utility is located in
>   flash_builder_install/sdks/4.0.0/bin.
>   You can only execute this utility from
>   the command line.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f2d.html

Comment: Thanks but I haven't added any other locales. I got past the compile error by including the flex 3 resource bundle SWC files in the library path as flex 2 had these as .properties files.

Comment: The config entry was: <library-path>
    <!--When using SDK 3.5 included the resource bundle SWCs directly to avoid errors finding rb source -->
   <path-element>.\sdks\3.5.0.12683\frameworks\locale\en_US\framework_rb.swc</path-element>
   <path-element>.\sdks\3.5.0.12683\frameworks\locale\en_US\rpc_rb.swc</path-element>

Comment: However the SWF built using the compc still fails with a Verify Error 1053: Illegal override of null. I am using the IDE built one at present.